# How do i disable installed version of Google Play services on my android device?

Tags: android, android-maps-v2, google-play-services

My application uses Google maps feature which needs Google Play services to be installed and enabled on the device.I wanted to test a case in which if Google play service has been disabled by user manually ask user to enable it so that application can work properly.SO i need to test my code against this case but I don't know how do I disable (not uninstall) Google play service on my phone and check if my code works properly.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Go to your device's `Settings --> Applications --> Tab "All" --> Google Play services` and press the `Disable` button.
It may pop up a dialog asking for a confirmation, in which case just answer OK.

Comment: I have Android 4.0.3. and the option to disable it just isn't there. Only to uninstall. I guess the situation in anks' case is the same. Neither of us want to uninstall it just for testing an app that uses it.

Comment: How about trying on another device. on the 4.0.3 device, if users can't disable GooglePlayServices, you might as well test it in a device or version that supports it.

Comment: This answer worked for me using the Android 5.0 API 21 x86x64 image with google play services in the emulator.

Answer (score 6):

Go to Setting then security then device administrator then the android one deactivate that one then back to the settings homepage then applications all and you can deactivate it

Answer (score 0):

If Google play services is not installed as a system app you won't have the option to disable it in system app settings, in this case where it's installed as a user app you can use an app like Titanium back up pro or link2SD to disable/freeze it.

Answer (score 0):

(Root Required) (Only tested on CM13 Note 10.1)

1. Close Play Store if open
2. Open ADB Shell (or Terminal on your rooted device) and type

   cd /data/app/*vending*

   mv base.apk base.apk.back

Answer (score 0):

### Disabling gapps

To disable all the apps that come with google's gapps you can use

`pm disable <PACKAGE_NAME>` (if rooted, run `su` once before this)

or

`pm hide <PACKAGE_NAME>` if not rooted.

### Re-enabling gapps

To re-enable the apps use

`pm enable <PACKAGE_NAME>` (if rooted run `su` once before this)

and

`pm unhide <PACKAGE_NAME>` (if not rooted).

Enabling can also be done via the **Settings** > **Apps** > **Show All apps** > (tap app name) > **Enable**.

The commands should be run either from `adb shell` when connected via cable, or directly on the device from a terminal.

Here is a list of packages (extracted from [open gapps mini](https://opengapps.org/)):

```sh
com.google.android.apps.turbo
com.google.android.apps.wallpaper
com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher
com.opengapps.wellbeingoverlay
com.google.android.tts
com.google.android.gm.exchange
com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox
com.opengapps.pixellauncheroverlay
com.google.android.syncadapters.calendar
com.google.android.gm
com.google.android.markup
com.google.android.packageinstaller
com.google.android.apps.wellbeing
com.google.android.calendar
com.google.android.soundpicker
com.google.android.ext.shared
com.google.android.setupwizard
com.google.android.apps.restore
com.google.android.onetimeinitializer
com.google.android.carriersetup
com.google.android.backuptransport
com.google.android.setupwizard
com.google.android.gms
com.google.android.apps.pixelmigrate
com.google.android.gsf
com.google.android.gms.policy_sidecar_aps
com.android.vending
com.google.android.ext.services
com.google.android.feedback
com.google.android.syncadapters.contacts
com.google.android.configupdater
com.google.android.partnersetup
```

> ❗️ **Use at your own risk! Make sure you backup your data before doing this**!

---

> <sup>*The list may vary depending on the version of android and CPU architecture.*</sup>

Answer (score -2):

I removed Google Play services from my Samsung phone as it was taking up a lot of space. 
Read everywhere on forums by experts of serious problems and later realised these were just copy & Paste from Google itself.

I went ahead and just uninstalled it and got bonus of much better battery too.
As I had sync on, Playstore still updated apps. So I disabled auto sync to do so manually for which I want as I do not really want maps etc;
Youtube refused to  start, so I now created a bookmark in my browser and access from there as anyhow I use my comp for downloads.

So if you have enough space just disable it in 'applications' or just remove it, your phone will function great - **forget the experts comments/views on different forums which are copy and paste opinions from Google**, you can always re-install if needed.

Answer (score -3):

I have an LG-E400 smart phone, I always had problems with lack of memory. I uninstalled Google PLay Services today and everything is working fine. Maps, Youtube, Internet, everything working as normal.